# How to make Bootstrap img-responsive stay within the boundaries of it's parent div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap 3, I'm trying to make an image stay within the boundaries of it's parent div.
This works fine for width, but no matter what I try, the image keeps falling out of the bottom of the parent div, because it's height doesn't update when I decrease browser height. Is it possible to make this work ? If so, how ? Thanks.

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rensdenobel/9486t/

HTML :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 center">
            <div class="content">
                <div id="text">You chose this photo :</div>            
                <div id="thumbnail-container">
                    <img id="thumbnail-image" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x800" />
                </div>
                <div id="button-share">
                        <button class="btn btn-success">Share it !</button>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-4"></div>        
    <div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.row {
    border:1px solid green;
    height:100%;
}

.center {
    display:table;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
    text-align:center;
    height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}

.content {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid green;
}

#thumbnail-image {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    height:auto;
}

#thumbnail-container{
    width:100%;   
    border:1px solid pink;
    max-height:70%;
    height:70%;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-bottom:12px;    
 }
```

Comment: When I removed Table, It works http://jsfiddle.net/9486t/11/

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<div id="thumbnail-container col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
   <img id="thumbnail-image" class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x800" />
 </div>
```

change the `col-sm-*` and `col-xs-*` to get your desired output

Comment: Thanks ! Doesn't seem to work, try it in the fiddle :  http://jsfiddle.net/rensdenobel/9486t/

Comment: What browser do you use ? When I resize the screen, so the height is smaller than the image, the image falls of the screen.

Comment: i use firefox,are you using IE?

Comment: Same result in Firefox & Chrome

Comment: did u check in the link i sent?

Comment: Your css is negating the responsive effect. remove the css and check

Comment: I'm not sure if you understand what I mean. On your bootply example, I get the exact same problem as I'm describing in my post. If I resize the browser to a smaller height, the image falls off the screen.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47428/discussion-between-arun-and-rens-de-nobel)

Comment: For new readers:  the result of the discussion was that, with the suggested solution, the height is left unchanged. So far, there's no solution for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This approach works for me. Please try adding this to your css:

```
.container {
     height:max-content;
}
```